# Spread overlapping points with similar but not identical coordinates

Tags: qgis

I've been looking for a solution for my problem for quite a while, but never found the answer.I have a lot of data point which are very close to each other, a lot of them have the same coordinates. The latter problem I can solve with the point displacement tool, however I still have remaining overlapping points.

Is there a way to spread the points that are overlapping, that have too close coordinates, but no identical ones with QGIS?

Comment: Snap all of them first to same coordinates with reasonable snapping tolerance and displace then? Never tried, might work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using the snapping tool, but nothing seems to change in the picture.

Comment: What could I be doing wrong. I chose snap to "OFF"